# Calling Jenkins from Slack slash command

Tags: rest, jenkins, jenkins-cli, slack-api

Is there a way to make a REST API call from Slack? I can use [Slash Commands](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands) to make GET/POST requests, but it seems I can't pass additional header parameters in the header.

I am trying to invoke a remote Jenkins script which requires passing the API token to authenticate the user. I don't want to write a middleware service between Slack and Jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a Node.js middleware.

Answer (score 0):

The bad news is it does require middleware, because Slack POSTs a specific body format which is beyond your control, so Jenkins' REST API wouldn't understand it.

The good news is [there's already a Slack command for Jenkins](https://github.com/joshdholtz/jenkins-slack-command). It looks to be Heroku-specific, but you should be able to make it work on any server.